# SQL Server set number of Backup to retain

Tags: sql-server, backup, retention

I have already defined a SQL Server Agent job, in order to backup 'mydb' in a specific disk location.

```
BACKUP DATABASE [MYDB] TO  DISK = N'C:\Dummy.bak' WITH RETAINDAYS = 3;
```

I planned this job to be performed every day of the week, but not Sunday.
The question is: can I set to have n different backup instances in my bak file instead of using n retaindays parameter, AND to delete others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to get a clear understanding about parameter "RETAINDAYS" please go through this following blog [link](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2017/10/12/sql-server-retaindays-not-delete-backup-x-days/).

But if I get your issue correctly, your concern is to avoid the Job to execute on Sunday and I think this is configurable in the job scheduling setup. You can select or deselect any day from the week (Under Frequency section) to Execute the job as per your requirement.

Comment: Right, I have edited my question, I want to delete backups and to maintain only last 3 in same bak.

Comment: You can use the "Maintenance Clean up Task" in your maintenance plan to clean up backup files older than a certain number of days.

Comment: So you suggest to make different backups and to create a task that deletes expired ones. Ok I'll check it out.

Comment: Yes, that's the standard option.

Comment: Created different backup files, and defined retention. In management created some maintenance plans, and that's it. Thanks @mkRabbani.

Comment: You are most welcome @AndreaTaroni86. Nice that it helped.